# Workaround to add reminder in Google Inbox via Apple Watch 3 with voice

Tags: apple-watch

How can I add a reminder in Google Inbox via my Apple Watch 3 by voice, without using my iPhone?

When I had no Apple Watch I used to ask Siri to send an email to myself as a dirty hack instead of native Inbox reminders. But even this hack is not working with Apple Watch, because it redirects me to iPhone. So maybe there are even more tricky hacks, which include IFTTT or something?

Comment: Why google inbox over reminders? That's one of the my favorite use cases for Siri. "Remind me to call Bob tomorrow at 10:30am". Keep in mind I use Inbox for reminder pins all the time too.

Comment: @JBallin I just want to have all my tasks in one place. Btw, I use native iOS reminders too, but only for simple tasks with specific time, like "take pills". When it comes to long living reminders without certain time, I prefer to have it in Inbox. This way, I get a comprehensive to-do list in one place.

Comment: Got it, thanks for explaining. Personally, I think it’s best to keep your to-do list and emails separate, otherwise a spam email holds the same importance as a priority task. Additionally, reminders lets me have a priority, important, urgent, and low priority list to prioritize properly which I find helpful! “Add x to my priority list”